# How to use Google Fit API's RecordingClient for background collection of DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE?

Tags: java, android, google-fit-sdk

I proceeded as per [Google Fit examples](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) and subscribed to the RecordingClient for `DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE` with the following code (after requesting all needed permissions):

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
    .subscribe(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
        }
    });
```

On the Logcat, I receive the messagge `Successfully subscribed!`, so everything seems to be OK.
In addition, if I run the following code, to double check:

```
Fitness.getRecordingClient(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this))
    .listSubscriptions()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Subscription>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Subscription> subscriptions) {
            for (Subscription sc : subscriptions) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Active subscription for data type: " + sc.getDataType().getName());
            }
        }
    });
```

I receive the output:

```
D/mygpsapp.log: Active subscription for data type: com.google.location.sample
```

confirming that the subscription is indeed active.
However, if (after moving around for one hour, for testing) I try to read data back from the HistoryClient, with the following code:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
    .read(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();

Fitness.getHistoryClient(MainActivity.this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this))
    .readData(readRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "HistoryClient.readData: onSuccess()");
        DataSet dataSet;

        List<DataSet> dataSets = dataReadResponse.getDataSets();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "# of DataSets: " + dataSets.size());
        dataSet = dataReadResponse.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DataSet: " + dataSet);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DataSource: " + dataSet.getDataSource());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DataType: " + dataSet.getDataType());

        int count = 0;
        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data point #" + count++);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() + ", Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "\tSource: " + dp.getOriginalDataSource().getAppPackageName());
        }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "HistoryClient.readData: onFailure()", e);
        }
    });
```

I do get a relevant `DataSet`, but it is always empty:

```
D/mygpsapp.log: # of DataSets: 1
D/mygpsapp.log: DataSet: DataSet{d:location.sample:gms:default_location_samples []}
D/mygpsapp.log: DataSource: DataSource{derived:Application{com.google.android.gms}:default_location_samples:DataType{com.google.location.sample[latitude(f), longitude(f), accuracy(f), altitude(f)]}}
D/mygpsapp.log: DataType: DataType{com.google.location.sample[latitude(f), longitude(f), accuracy(f), altitude(f)]}
```

I acknowledge that the Google Fit API documentation [reports the following](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#exceptions):

> Exceptions: Whilst any application can write data to a public data
>   type, there are certain data types which can only be read by the
>   application that wrote the data:
>
> com.google.location.sample, The user's current location.

but I *do* try to read back the data with *the same application*.
What makes me suspicious is that the previous Logcat seems to indicate that the application that wrote the data is `com.google.android.gms` (is it the RecordingClient?) not mine, possibly explaining why the DataSet returns empty. But if this is the case, how is my application supposed to read back the data that itself asked (*succesfully!*) to record?

Comment: If I try the above with a different `DataType` (e.g. `DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT`) everything seems to work perfectly. This seems to indicate that the issue is indeed with `DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Fit does not support reading location data which has been gathered via the Recording API via the History API.

We'll clarify this in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Graeme. Does the final mention "via the History API" mean that there are perhaps other ways to read back such data?

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply.) No, it doesn't.